# Django 1.9.2 test Client issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm using `Django==1.9.2` and `djangorestframework==3.3.2`, and `django.test.Client` to make some tests. The problem is that when I execute my tests I'm gettting this error:

```
ERROR: test_view (main.tests.test_http.TestMainViewSet)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/saxo-publish/publish/main/tests/test_http.py", line 111, in test_view
    content_type='application/json'
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 515, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 314, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 380, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 449, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 123, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 245, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 296, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 166, in _wrapped_view
    return middleware.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/vladir/work/all/project-django1.9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 230, in process_response
    request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"],
KeyError: u'CSRF_COOKIE'
```

My test code looks like this:

```
import json

from django.test import Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TestMainViewSet(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client(
            HTTP_HOST='example.com' # I have also tried removing this
        )
        self.create_read_url = reverse('books-list')
        User.objects.create_user(
            username="username",
            email="username@zunzun.se",
            password="123"
        ) 

    def test_create(self):
        self.client.login(username='username', password="123")
        # In this case I'm doing a POST, but it is the same with a GET
        response = self.client.post(
            self.create_read_url,
            data=json.dumps({'title': "Create"}), # I have also tried without the json.dumps
            content_type='application/json'
        )

        data = json.loads(response.content)
        print data

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        self.assertEquals(data['title'], "Create")
```

my `view` code is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serialiazers import (
    BookSerializerRead,
    BookSerializerWrite,
)

class MainViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class_read = BookSerializerRead
    serializer_class_write = BookSerializerWrite
```

on the `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'books', MainViewSet, 'books')


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

According with the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/) about it, I should not need anything additional to avoid the `CSRF checks`,
because as textually said there: "By default, the test client will disable any CSRF checks performed by your site.", and I also know that `enforce_csrf_checks=False` by default
on the `Client`.

I have found one detail though, if I create an instance of the client that way `self.client = Client(HTTP_HOST='example.com', CSRF_COOKIE='xxxxxx')` then it works, but is that
actually needed? It is not what the documentation says, so I suppose I'm doing something wrong. Could someone help me with that please? I will appreciate any help about.
Thanks in advance

Comment: DRF provides different testing mechanisms, you may want to try those: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @TomCarrick, very useful, I have not used it before. I will test this, for sure. My main question is what changed from `Django 1.8.4` to `Django 1.9.2` that broken this? And from my point of view it is something related with `Django` itself, at the end it is a request as `json` to a `Django Rest Framework` endpoint, it should have worked, I think :(. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DRF's APITestCase as base class for test cases:

```
from rest_framework.testing import APITestCase

class TestMainViewSet(APITestCase):
    ...
```

Comment: should be ```from rest_framework.testimport APITestCase```